# How to know the target element that raised the event in the ajax response callback?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events

I am posting to the server using jquery ajax using $.post. After server returns the response, I process the response in  the callback function. In this callback function, how can I know which element was clicked on. Please check the following. In the function handleServerResponse, I would like to know the DOM element that raised this event. Precise I want to access the $(this) element available in handleFavouritesUI function. I am using jquery with ASP.NET MVC.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $("a.favourite-on, a.favourite-off").click(handleFavouritesUI);
    });

    function handleFavouritesUI(e) {
        var link = $(this).attr("href");

        $.post(link, handleServerResponse);


        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    function handleServerResponse(data, textStatus) {
        response = eval(data);

        var targetElement = null;
        // TODO: get the target element.  

        if (!response.success) {
            showMessage(targetElement, response.reason, true);
        }
        else {
            //TODO: Modify the target element.  
        }
    }  


</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the handleServerResponse to an inline function...

```
function handleFavouritesUI(e) {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");

    $.post(link, function(data,textStatus){
        var targetElement = null;
        if (!response.success) {
            showMessage(targetElement, response.reason, true);
        }
        else {
            // See, the link object still holds the same reference.
            link.fadeOut().fadeIn();
        }
    });

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Read up a bit on [closures in JavaScript](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=closures+javascript) to better understand how this works.